# How to call a Java program from a Clojure program ?

Tags: java, clojure, functional-programming

```
package javaCodes;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class interm3parse {
public static boolean checkGroup(String str)throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String line = null;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if(line.contains(str))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return false;

}
public static boolean checkPresence(String str) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String line = null;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if(line.startsWith(str))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return false;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new       FileWriter("filepath"));
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filepath");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s=new String();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        s="";
        if(!line.startsWith("defmeasure")||(line==null))
         {
         String[] splitArray = line.split("\\s");
         s=s+splitArray[0];
         //System.out.println(splitArray[0]);
         for(int i=1;i<splitArray.length;i++)
          {
            if(splitArray[i].contains("/"))
            {
                String[] alias = splitArray[i].split("/");
                if(checkPresence(alias[1])||checkGroup(alias[1]))
                {
                    s=s+" "+alias[1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                s=s+" "+splitArray[i];
            }
          }
         pw.write(s);
         pw.println();
         System.out.println(s);

         }
        else
        {
            //fw.write(line);
            //fw.write("\n");
            System.out.println(line);
            pw.write(line);
            pw.println();   
        }
        }
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

}//main

}//end of class
```

I have a user defined Java program (interm3parse.java) ;I want to call that program(functions) from clojure program ....Both the codes are working fine individually ..Java code is in javaCodes package........................clojure code is in anothernamespace.................................

```
Clojure code

(ns javaCodes.generalizedmeasuretocomp )

(defn output-Measure-Criterias-Final []
;;;Java program to replace all group components and remove aliases 

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [call Java code from Clojure](http://call%20Java%20code) (assuming Java code classes are on Clojure application's classpath):

As your Java class defines static methods you can call them like that:

```
(ns javaCodes.generalizedmeasuretocomp
  (:import javaCodes.interm3parse))

(defn output-Measure-Criterias-Final []
  (javaCodes.interm3parse/checkGroup "some string"))
```

By the way I noticed that your Java code might not work correcly (but I guess it is only for illustration purposes). It uses some undefined names (e.g. `filepath`) and it might leak resources (when it returns `true` it won't close the input stream).

I think you should wrap your resources into [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, or write that code in Clojure using `with-open`:

```
(defn file-line-starts-with-str? [filename s]
  (with-open [reader (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
    (->> reader
      (line-seq)
      (some #(clojure.string/starts-with? % s)))))
```

Comment: Hey ,@Piotrek Bzdyl i tried converting the java file(interm3parse.java) to a jar file(interm3parse.jar) ... and added it to the classpath(add jar) of my clojure project.. and i do (import interm3parse.interm3parse ) but it says Classnotfound exception .. what do i do now ??

Comment: How are you starting your Clojure app? Did you add your `iterm3parse.jar` to Clojure app classpath?

Comment: i just run the clojure program.right click->load file in REPL ..when i do that it gives class not found exception...

Comment: Approach2: i created a java program inside the clojure project (test.java)..and when i do (ns auto-update.core (:import autoupdate.test ))...again it says class not found exception... i have been trying this from a day now.. how do i resolve this ???

Comment: From your comments I am guessing you are using Cursive. Cursive uses lein as its project model, so you need to follow instructions on lein's website for [projects containing Java code](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/MIXED_PROJECTS.md#polyglot-clojure-java-projects-with-leiningen). That probably includes moving Clojure source under `src/clojure` and Java sources under `src/java` and updating `project.clj` accordingly.

Comment: thank you  Piotrek Bzdyl for your help ... ill try mavenizing the project and then try .. :)

Comment: You are welcome. You should be able to do this with lein as described in the link I provided.